# How to refresh random number on click listener?

Tags: java, android, random

I have managed to create a simple guessing game (this works fine) the only problem is I cant seem to refresh the random number that I generate at the  start. (when they have correctly guessed the number)

```
import java.util.Random;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private TextView hint;
private Button enterGuess;
private EditText chosenNumber;

Random rand = new Random();
int secretNumber = rand.nextInt(99) + 1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    enterGuess = findViewById(R.id.buttonEnter);
    chosenNumber = findViewById(R.id.etEnterNumber);
    hint = findViewById(R.id.tvHint);

    final String hintHigh = "Guess Higher";
    final String hintLow = "Guess Lower";
    final String correctGuess = "Correct! Guess the new number!";


    enterGuess.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            int number = Integer.parseInt(chosenNumber.getText().toString());

            if (number < secretNumber){
                hint.setText(hintHigh);
            }
            else if (number > secretNumber) {
                hint.setText(hintLow);
            }
            else {
                hint.setText(correctGuess);

                Random rand = new Random();
                int secretNumber = rand.nextInt(99) + 1;

            }
        }
    });
}
}
```

Comment: You should clarify your question. What happens and what should happen? Right now it's unclear.

Comment: Please use code formatting for code and code snippets, structured documents like HTML/XML or input/output.  To do that, select the text and click the `{}` button at the top of the message posting/editing form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should update your instance variable secretNumber, so inside your onClick() method :

```
this.secretNumber = rand.nextInt(99) + 1;
```

Comment: This solves the issue with hiding the class field but does not help regarding to generate it since his `if-else` clauses may stay in the first branch forever.

Comment: @Murat as far as I understand the OP wants to generate a new random only in the case of a correct guess. So to me the only issue with his code was that he wasn't updating properly the instance variable when a correct guess was made

Answer (score -2):

Don't create a new instance of Random every time you want the game to be restarted. just call nextInt(99) on the instance you already have.

Comment: This does not provide any answer whatsoever.

Comment: yes it does. This should fix the issue that the random number does not change when the game restarts

Comment: Of course besides the fact that secretNumber should not be a local variable.